# Plot graph with multiple attributes similar to "hue" in Seaborn

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following sample data set called `df`, where stage time is how many days to get there:

```
id stage1_time stage_1_to_2_time stage_2_time stage_2_to_3_time stage3_time
a  10          30                40           30                70
b  30               
c  15          30                45     
d
```

I wrote the following script to get a scatter plot of `stage1_time` against a CDF:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

dict = {'id': id, 'stage_1_time': [10, 30, 15, None], 'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'stage_2_time' : [40, None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None, None],'stage_3_time' : [70, None, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

#create eCDF function
def ecdf(df):
    n = len(df)
    x = np.sort(df)
    y = np.arange(1.0, n+1) / n
    return x, y

def generate_scatter_plot(df):

    x, y = ecdf(df)

    plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none') 
    plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) #Add mean

    x_m = int(x.mean())
    y_m = stats.percentileofscore(df.as_matrix(), x.mean())/100.0

    plt.annotate('(%s,%s)' % (x_m,int(y_m*100)) , xy=(x_m,y_m), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

    percentiles= np.array([0,25,50,75,100])
    x_p = np.percentile(df, percentiles)
    y_p = percentiles/100.0

    plt.plot(x_p, y_p, marker='D', color='red', linestyle='none') # Overlay quartiles

    for x,y in zip(x_p, y_p):                                        
        plt.annotate('%s' % int(x), xy=(x,y), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

#Data to plot
stage1_time = df['stage_1_time'].dropna().sort_values()

#Scatter Plot
stage1_time_scatter = generate_scatter_plot(pd.DataFrame({"df" : stage1_time.as_matrix()}))
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Days to Stage1')
plt.xlabel('Days to Stage1')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Probability')
plt.legend(('Days to Stage1', "Mean", 'Quartiles'), loc='lower right')
plt.margins(0.02)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Currently I have number of days it took all who reached `stage1` plotted against its cumulative probability, however what I am trying to achieve is that the scatter has three colors when I plot: those who reached `stage1` and stayed there, those who moved on to `stage2`, and those who moved on to `stage3`. I would also like the counts for the data in the graph: # in `stage1`, # in `stage2` and # in `stage3`.

Can anyone assist with getting there please?

FYI, intention is to use this as a base so that I can also create a graph for `stage2_time`, where those reaching `stage_3` are highlighted a different color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new column and use it to store the final stage, then use this new column to color your plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math

dict = {'id': id, 'Progressive_time': [10, 30, 15, None],'stage_1_to_2_time': [30, None, 30, None], 'Active_time' : [40,None, 45, None],'stage_2_to_3_time' : [30, None, None,None],'Engaged_time' : [70, None, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

    #create eCDF function
def ecdf(df, serie):
    n = len(df)
    df['x'] = np.sort(df[serie])
    df['y'] = np.arange(1.0, n+1) / n
    return df

def generate_scatter_plot(df,serie,nb_stage):
    df=df.dropna(subset=[serie]).sort_values(by=[serie])
    st=1
    for i in range(1,nb_stage*2,2):
        df.loc[df.iloc[:,i].notnull(),'stage']=st
        st=st+1

    df= ecdf(df, serie)
    plt.plot(df.loc[df['stage'] == 1, 'x'], df.loc[df['stage'] == 1, 'y'], marker='.', linestyle='none',c='blue') 
    plt.plot(df.loc[df['stage'] == 2, 'x'], df.loc[df['stage'] == 2, 'y'], marker='.', linestyle='none',c='red') 
    plt.plot(df.loc[df['stage'] == 3, 'x'], df.loc[df['stage'] == 3, 'y'], marker='.', linestyle='none',c='green') 
    plt.axvline(df['x'].mean(), color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) #Add mean


    x_m = int(df['x'].mean())
    y_m = stats.percentileofscore(df[serie], df['x'].mean())/100.0

    plt.annotate('(%s,%s)' % (x_m,int(y_m*100)) , xy=(x_m,y_m), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

    percentiles= np.array([0,25,50,75,100])
    x_p = np.percentile(df[serie], percentiles)
    y_p = percentiles/100.0

    plt.plot(x_p, y_p, marker='D', color='red', linestyle='none') # Overlay quartiles

    for x,y in zip(x_p, y_p):                                        
        plt.annotate('%s' % int(x), xy=(x,y), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

#Scatter Plot
stage1_time_scatter = generate_scatter_plot(df,'stage_1_time',3)
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Days to Stage1')
plt.xlabel('Days to Stage1')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Probability')
plt.legend(('Progressive','Active','Engaged','Days to Stage1', "Mean", 'Quartiles'), loc='lower right')
plt.margins(0.02)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Question, about `def generate_scatter_plot`- is there any way to take out the hard coded `stage_3_time` and `stage_2_time` from the definition itself? I am hoping to be able to use it more broadly for other situations too?

Comment: I edited my code.

Now in `generate_scatter_plot` you can set a number of stages.
For the plot legend, you may edit or add a list in `generate_scatter_plot`

Comment: Thank you! two questions: 1) I called stages 1,2,3 but in actuality they are alphabet definitions (like Progressive, Active, Engaged) - can I still use the code as is? 2) If I needed, is it generic enough be used used for those who received a certain email for example (which would be a different series ie column in df) instead of those continuing to stage 2 and 3?

Comment: you must use the same structure for colomne of the datframe but the name is not important

Comment: Thank you this is really great! See question in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172432/discussion-between-user8834780-and-aurelia-b